# Append a form value to a textbox

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to take the value selected in a dropdown box and append it to another textbox on my page using JQuery.

*take the value from this form*

```
<form id="val">
<select>
<option value="Counseling General CBI Determinations">CBI Determinations</option>
<option value="Counseling General Correspondence">Correspondence</option>
<option value="Counseling General Memorandum">Memorandum</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="append">apply filter</button>
</form>
```

*Append to this textbox*

```
<input name="txtBox" type="text"/>
```

Comment: `option` tag must be in `select` tag. You html isn't valid

Comment: Where's the jQuery you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to fix your html, options need to be inside a [`select`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) 
then you can do it in the click event handler for the button.

```js
$('#append').click(function() {
  var selectedVal = $('#mySelect').val();
  $('input[name="txtBox"]').val(selectedVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="val">
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
      <option value="Counseling General CBI Determinations">CBI Determinations</option>
      <option value="Counseling General Correspondence">Correspondence</option>
      <option value="Counseling General Memorandum">Memorandum</option>
    </select>
<button type="button" id="append">apply filter</button>
</form>
Append to this textbox

<input name="txtBox" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure and put your option elements in a select after having done so your html should read:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="val">
    <select id="selectBox">
      <option value="Counseling General CBI Determinations">CBI Determinations</option>
      <option value="Counseling General Correspondence">Correspondence</option>
      <option value="Counseling General Memorandum">Memorandum</option>
    </select>
<button type="button" id="append">apply filter</button>
</form>
Append to this textbox

<input name="txtBox" type="text"/>
```

After having done this you can use jquery:

```
$('input[name="txtBox"]').val($("#selectBox").val());
```